# Unable to download excel file from asset/test.xlsx on IE and Edge browser

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

I tried with anchor tag and download attribute but it’s not working in IE and Edge and sometimes it’s working in chrome but sometimes it is not. I tried to use navigator.msSaveBlob function but I am not sure how to use it for excel file which is available in my angular project at asset folder. Please let me know if you have any solutions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `it’s working in chrome but sometimes it is not` that's not helpful - what happens (in the developer console) when it fails? What happens (in the browser developer console) in IE and Edge when it fails

Comment: What's your router config in Angular? Probably something's wrong with it.

Comment: @jaromanda first of all I am not sure how to do with all the steps and it’s not showing anything in console

Comment: @maxim I declared ‘./asset/test.xlsx’ for xhr.open

Answer (score 0):

```
if(navigator.msSaveBlob)
{
    // For IE/Edge
    let data: any;
    this.HttpService
       .get("assets/sample.xlsx",{responseType: 'text'})
       .subscribe((res:any) => {
                                data = res;
                                let byteCharacters = atob(data);
                                let byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
                                 for(let i=0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                                 byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
                                 }
                                let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                                let blob = new Blob([byteArray],{type:'application/vnd.ms-excel});
                                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob,'sample.xlsx');
                              });
  }
else if(!navigator.msSaveBlob)
{
   // For Non-IE
   let link = document.createElement("a");
   link.href = "assets/sample.xlsx";
   link.download = "sample.xlsx";
   link.click();
   window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
   link.remove();
}
```